# Problem with publishing to Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tomcat9

We have a war built with Maven which depends on a couple jars (other java projects in Eclipse workspace).

We deploy the project using the Eclipse Tomcat9 plugin. Deploy path is -Dwtp.deploy="C:\Users\MrX\eclipse\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps"

This was working fine until now. But since we added a new library the eclipse server doesn't start.

Eclipse includes the new jar in the directory above but for some reason the jar doesn't include the source code (only the resources).

I initially thought it was an issue with the build so I double checked the classpath / deployment assembly / build config.

The build seems fine: when I export the war built in the target folder to Tomcat directly (rather than deploying with the Eclipse plugin) it works as expected.

If I manually copy the jar of the new library we added to in the wtpwebapps folder and then start the eclipse tomcat: it works as well.

So it seems to be some kind of a refresh issue, or maybe an issue during the deploy of the new lib.

Do you know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, the deployment assembly of the lib had /WEB-INF/ in the deploy path instead of / for one of the source folders.